# bash copy file to new desintation if it doesnt exists make a new directory

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Hello i am currently optimizing some code i have and am now wondering why this snippet of code does not work.

what is supposed to happen is when i copy the file i have to type in a destination for the copy if i type a destination that doesn't exist then the script will create a directory and copy that file to it.

this is what i have and i am wondering why it is not working

```
echo "Current Directory "
        ls -a;
        echo -n "Please Enter file name to Copy: "
        read fileToCopy
        echo -n "Enter Destination for Copy: ~/ "
        read location
        if [ -d $location ]
        then
                cp $fileToCopy $location
                echo "File Successfully Copied to ~/ $location "
        elif [ !-d $location ]
        then
                mkdir $location
                cp $fileToCopy $location
                echo "$location was created and the File was Copied to It! "
                echo -n "Press Enter to Continue: "
        else
                echo "That file Does Not Exist! "
        fi
```

Comment: one problem seems to be, that you need a space in elif [ !-d $location ] between ! and -d: elif [ ! -d $location ]

Comment: duhh im such an idiot sometimes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Two issues:

#### One:

`elif [ !-d $location ]`

You need a space between `!` and `-d`.

#### Two:

**Quote** your variables.

Answer (score 0):

It's always good to error check. What if the user didn't enter a directory name or a file to copy?

In shell, a null variable will cause an error in a statement like this:

```
if [ $dir -eq foo ]
then
    …
fi
```

That's because the shell will directly substitute the value and then interpret the line. If `$dir` is null, the statement will be:

```
if [ -eq foo ]
then
    …
fi
```

This isn't valid. If you had quotes around `$dir`:

```
if [ "$dir" -eq foo ]
then
    …
fi
```

You'd get this:

```
if [ "" -eq foo ]
then
    …
fi
```

Which is valid.

If you're using bash it's preferable to use the double square brackets:

```
if [[ $dir -eq foo ]]
then
    …
fi
```

This is a special *improved* syntactic test that will handle null variables and variables with spaces without having to use quotes.

The `!` is a special shell operator that negates the return value of a command/statement. For the shell to understand the operator, you must make sure there is white space on either side of it. Also test the output of your `mkdir` statement to make sure it worked. And use the `-p` parameter. This will create parent directories.

```
 if [[ ! -d "$dir" ]]
 then
     if ! mkdir -p "$dir" 
     then
         echo "Could not create dir '$dir'" 1>&2
         exit 2
     fi
 fi
```

Note that I always put quotes around my variable and I use the `if` statement to test to see if my command succeeded or not. After all, the user might have tried to create a directory where I don't have write permission.

One more secret trick. You can use `set -xv` to turn on shell script debugging. This will print out each statement as written and then as the shell interprets it. To turn it off use `set +xv`.